# Are smooth Schubert varieties Kähler?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, dg.differential-geometry, complex-geometry, lie-algebras, kahler-manifolds

Schubert variety $V$ is a special type of (possibly singular) subvarieties of a Grassmannian. Since the Grassmannians are Kähler manifolds (in fact projective varieties) are we able to conclude that any smooth Schubert subvariety of a Grassmannian is in fact also a Kähler manifold?

Comment: Schubert varieties are also projective varieties, doesn't that answer your question?...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, smooth closed subvarieties of projective varieties are projective, and hence Kahler. Smooth Schubert varieties are very rare though, see the sources below for a description of them:

*Ryan, Kevin M.*, [**On Schubert varieties in the flag manifold of Sl(n,({\mathbb C}))**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/BF01450738), Math. Ann. 276, 205-224 (1987). [ZBL0579.14045](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0579.14045).

*Wolper, James S.*, [**A combinatorial approach to the singularities of Schubert varieties**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/0001-8708(89)90048-0), Adv. Math. 76, No. 2, 184-193 (1989). [ZBL0705.14048](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0705.14048).

*Gasharov, V.; Reiner, V.*, [**Cohomology of smooth Schubert varieties in partial flag manifolds**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1112/S0024610702003605), J. Lond. Math. Soc., II. Ser. 66, No. 3, 550-562 (2002). [ZBL1064.14056](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1064.14056).